# Slick - Error value <> is not a member of - while using ForeignKey

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I am using Slick to connect to a `PostgresDB`

I have defined three tables:

```
Brand, Category, Item  
case class Category(categoryId: UUID,name:String)  
case class Brand(id:UUID, name: String)
```

```
case class Item(
                 id: UUID,
                 name: String,
                 description: String,
                 price: BigDecimal,
                 brand: Brand,
                 category: Category
               )
```

Below are the mappings for slick tables

```
class BrandTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Brand](tag, Some("shopping"), "Brand") {

  def id: Rep[UUID] = column[UUID]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.Unique)

  def name: Rep[String] = column[String]("name", O.Unique)

  override def * : ProvenShape[Brand] = (id, name) <> (Brand.tupled, Brand.unapply)
}

class CategoryTable(tag:Tag) extends Table[Category](tag, Some("shopping"), "Category"){

  def id = column[UUID]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.Unique)
  def name = column[String]("name",O.Unique)
  override def * : ProvenShape[Category] = (id, name) <>(Category.tupled, Category.unapply)
}
class ItemTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Item](tag, Some("shopping"), "Items") {

  implicit val uuidColumnType: BaseColumnType[UUID] = MappedColumnType.base[UUID, String](
    _.toString,
    UUID.fromString
  )
  def id = column[UUID]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.Unique)

  def name = column[String]("name")

  def description = column[String]("description")

  def price = column[BigDecimal]("price")

  def brandId = column[UUID]("brand_id")

  def categoryId = column[UUID]("category_id")

  //Mapping to Brand Table
  def brand: ForeignKeyQuery[BrandTable, Brand] =
    foreignKey("brand_fk", brandId, SlickTables.brandTable)(_.id)

  def category: ForeignKeyQuery[CategoryTable, Category] =
    foreignKey("category_fk", categoryId, SlickTables.categoryTable)(_.id)

  override def * : ProvenShape[Item] =
    (id, name, description, price, brand, category) <> ( Item.tupled, Item.unapply)
}
```

BrandTable and CategoryTable are working as expected.
But I am seeing issues with ItemTable when I try to define the foreign key

```
override def \* : ProvenShape\[Item\] =
(id, name, description, price, brand, category) \<\> ( Item.tupled, Item.unapply)
```

throws compile error:

```
value <> is not a member of (slick.lifted.Rep[java.util.UUID], slick.lifted.Rep[String], slick.lifted.Rep[String], slick.lifted.Rep[BigDecimal], slick.lifted.ForeignKeyQuery[tables.BrandTable,model.Brand], slick.lifted.ForeignKeyQuery[tables.CategoryTable,model.Category])
    (id, name, description, price, brand, category) <> (Item.tupled, Item.unapply _)
```

I have the import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.*api*._ added <> should work
I am not sure why I am seeing this error
Can some please suggest.

Comment: the class `ItemTable` extends `Table[Item]`. item table has the fields `brand: Brand` and `category: Category` but you defined the columns for those fields as `brandId = column[UUID]` and `categoryId = column[UUID]`. Could you clarify what are the columns and types you have for each table and what would be the queries you would like to produce?

Comment: I was using Brand and Category in the case class Item instead of BrandId and CategoryID. 
updated case class Item to use BrandId and CategoryId. it worked